ROR + Trying to create Composite Primary Keys for Partitioning using ID column & created_at column and got lots of error while fetching the record
Trying to create Composite Primary Keys for Partitioning using ID column & created_at column and got lots of errors while fetching the record
Model: Receipt
class Receipt < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = %i[id created_at]
end

Error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[:id, :created_at]' for #<Receipt:0x00008>):


Here, passing of created_at is not possible. Is there any other option or way to partition the date based on date?

@dbugger - just added the screenshot. please have a look

Do not add screen shots -https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

And odds are good the issue is in your receipts partial

Full stacktrace is always worth more than people give it credit for but I can recreate the actual error message using "".send('[:id,:created_at]') so  receipt.send(receipt.primary_key.to_s) would do it.
